# convert vector to raster in qgis

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to convert some vector layers(format shp) to raster, to do so I used the following method raster-->conversion-->(vector to raster) and the processing works without any problem. However the result of the conversion is not satisfying at all I got just a black image. I don't know from where the problem is.

[image]

Comment: Adding screenshots of the options you used and the resulting output could help people answer your question

Comment: Have you tried to change your layer's CRS ?

Comment: What type of geometry are you trying to convert? Is it polygon, polyline, or point? Please update your question to include the geometry type.

Comment: I use WGS84 similar to the map projection

Answer (score 1):

Layer Properties: In style manager try to assign colors, singleband pseudocolors

Comment: already tried but in vain I got one color.

Comment: can you make a screenshot of your raster-style settings?

Comment: You also need to force it to assess the actual min-max of your raster.  You can do that under Load Min/Max Values by setting the accuracy to actual.