# Shapefile conversion to ascii grid

Tags: shapefile, convert, ascii

I'm working with *shapefile* files, but I need to convert to *ASCII grid*, and I was trying to use *QGIS*, but the following error occurred:

```
File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/GdalTools/tools/dialogBase.py", line 208, in onFinished
            msg = unicode(self.process.readAllStandardError())
        UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 24: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am new to the area, when I am doing the conversion, only my *shapefile* file is enough? Can I perform this procedure in *GDAL*?

I know there are related questions, but none ends up solving the problem.

Comment: What is encoding of your shapfile ?

Comment: Shapefiles are vectors but ASCII is a raster format, you want to use *GDAL_rasterize* https://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html but first, have you got a full set of files? You should have at the very least a .shp, .dbf and .shx file with the same root name. Related question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250270/convert-vector-to-raster-in-qgis

Comment: What do you have in the shapefile? Perhaps points with measures which should be interpolated into a grid, or what?

Comment: Hi @ahsan-mukhtar I do not know, but I used QGIS and OpenStreetMap to create the shapfile.

Comment: Hi @michael-stimson. yes, i have the above files, i am try the procedure.

Comment: Hi @user30184 are street and buildings.

Comment: In that case ASCII grid is an exotic selection as a format but I trust that you have some good reason for that.

Comment: Most probably you have data in your attribute field that can not be converted to ASCII. It might help if you add your command line to your question.

Comment: @andrej was trying to accomplish using the QGIS

Comment: @user30184 I do not have much experience with gis, I'm following an example work using geomason and mason that ends up using ascii grid

Comment: It would be kind to mention that in your question and add a link to the example if it is public. What is geomason?